# Google apps script - Function cannot call another function from auto trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an API function to extract data from Amazon, I need to have 'fetch' & 'get' report function separately to achieve action for

1. request fetching report from Amazon, and
2. get report from Amazon, and the request action take about 2 mins for Amazon to finish the fetching request and allow for getting the report, so in the script I have set `script.newtrigger` after 2 minutes.

```
function fetchReportMarketListTrig() {
  fetchReportMarketList(true);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("getReportsForAccountMarketListTrig")
  .timeBased()
  .after(2* 60 * 1000)
  .create();
  Logger.log("Report Request Created");
}
```

The function worked perfectly when I manual trigger it from `menuitems`, `getReportsForAccountMarketListTrig` will be called after 2 minutes. However, if I set auto trigger, `fetchReportMarketListTrig` cannot call `getReportsForAccountMarketListTrig`. we need to seek the answer of why the sheet is acting different from manual trigger and auto trigger. Thanks a lot!

[Manual trigger from menuitems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvSQm.png)

[Auto trigger set in google sheet time-driven trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3w5J.png)

[Auto Trigger and Manual trigger execution result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udvnI.png)

Comment: How are you triggering `fetchReportMarketListTrig`?

Comment: Hi @RafaGuillermo,
Thank you so much for the response, I just added the screencap for how I manual trigger and auto trigger fetchReportMarketListTrig in the flag.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You have two functions with the same name! This produced undefined behaviour when you create a trigger for this function.*

#### More Information:

In the screenshot you provided for your trigger, you are displayed the following warning:

[image]

Functions within the same project ***must always have a unique name!***

Imagine the following code:

```
function doSomeMath() {
  var x = 1 + 2;
  console.log(x);
}

function doSomeMath() {
  var x = 100 + 200;
  console.log(x);
}
```

And then you ask your trigger to run function `doSomeMath()` - how does it know which one you mean?

#### Fix:

The likelyhood here is that the other function in your code canned `fetchReportMarketListTrig` is what is running on the time-based trigger, and not the one you intend to have run.

To fix this, search your script file for the functions named `fetchReportMarketListTrig`, and rename them so that they are unique. You can then set up your trigger on the function you wish as normal.